# Конструкция try with resources на API меньше 19

Tags: android, api

устройство поддерживает максимум 16 уровень, 
а программе нужен минимум 19

> Try-with-resources requires API level 19 (current min is 16)

```
try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {    //красный
  //code
  //code
  //code
  try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost)) { //красный
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(                        //красный
      new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())))) {    //красный
    }
  }
}
return output;
```

//красный- это строки с ошибкой

можно ли использовать какую нибудь другую конструкцию или костыль для работы моей программы с 16 версией API ?

Comment: Если это андроид код, то вы врядли что-то сделаете,  ищите другой способ. Если это библиотека и вы уверены что она будет работать на 16 апи, можете сделать в манифесте overwride api.

Answer (score 2):

Конкретно по сообщению в вашем вопросе, ограничение по API связано с тем, что конструкция `try-with-resources` введена начиная с Java 7, поддержка Java 7 в Android осуществляется начиная с API19 (ревизия SDK Tools 22.6) и использовать эту языковую конструкцию на меньшем API не получится в общем случае.

Вы можете использовать обычные блоки try - catch, как это делали до появления Java 7, немного изменив обработку исключения либо попробовать (я не проверял, будет ли это работать) использовать [новый компилятор Jack](https://habrahabr.ru/company/intel/blog/276881/), который поддерживает конструкции Java 7 (кроме аннотаций) и не имеет ограничения по API (находится в процессе разработки и имеет некоторые ограничения, так же возможны проблемы)

PS: в [этой теме](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7153989) предлагаются некоторые костыли, но сам я не пробовал и ничего о их применимости сказать не могу.